# What does the "ref" do in this React code

Tags: reactjs, ref

I'm a beginner and read lots of code and this one I cant find any docs on

How does that work I cant see that `ref` is used in the `Slider` or maybe it is

[image]

The file:

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
import React from 'react';
import Resume from '../../resume.json';
import albums from '../../albumData.json';

const la = require('lodash');

class SliderWrapper extends React.Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        // certain condition here, perhaps comparison between this.props and nextProps
        // and if you want to update slider on setState in parent of this, return true, otherwise return false
        const { updateCount } = nextProps;
        const { updateCounter } = this.props;

        if (updateCounter !== updateCount) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    sliders() {
        return Resume.weeks.map(week => {
            let photo = la.find(albums, { weekNumber: week.weekNumber });
            photo = encodeURIComponent(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/weeks/${week.weekNumber}/${photo.coverImage}`);
            const { onImageClick } = this.props;

            return (
                // Timeline items
                <section className="timeline-carousel" key={week.weekNumber}>
                    <h1>week {week.weekNumber}</h1>
                    <div className="timeline-carousel__item-wrapper" data-js="timeline-carousel">
                        <div className="timeline-carousel__item">
                            <div className="timeline-carousel__image">
                                <img onClick={() => onImageClick(week.weekNumber)} alt="CoverImage" src={photo} />
                                <h2>UNDER CONSTRUCTION IN PROGRES..</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div className="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                                <div className="pointer" />
                                <span className="year">{week.year}</span>
                                <span className="month">{week.albumDate}</span>
                                <p>{week.summary}</p>
                                <a href="#/" className="read-more">
                                    Read more, Dev should go to read more
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { afterChanged } = this.props;
        const { beforeChanged } = this.props;
        const settings = {
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            autoplay: false,
            infinite: true,
            lazyLoad: false,
            swipeToSlide: true,
            centerMode: false,
            focusOnSelect: false,
            className: 'center',
            slidesToShow: 4,
            afterChange: afterChanged,
            beforeChange: beforeChanged,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3,
                        infinite: false,
                    },
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2,
                        initialSlide: 2,
                    },
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                    },
                },
            ],
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <Slider
                    ref={slider => {
                        this.slider = slider;
                    }}
                    {...settings}
                >
                    {this.sliders()}
                </Slider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SliderWrapper;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

Checkout [ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for more information

Comment: Thanks god it! In the code the `this.slider = slider` is that even doing anything since `this.slider` is not a variable in the constructor or in the class, and not called or used anywhere